Feature dependence in Random Forest application
I'm applying a Random Forest Regression on target variable y, number of items bought
At the time of running the regression, I will have access to the 'running total' of variable y so far at time n minutes before.
E.g. If I ran the regression 0 minutes before the end of the experiment, my value of the running total of number of items bought will just be the target variable itself for this example.
I want to use this as a feature in my regression, amongst a few I already have, since it gives me a valuable insight not offered by my other features. The time at which the regression is run will vary, so n could be anything.
For training data, I can sample this running total of items bought at set intervals since I have a time series. For test data I can't do this.
For this reason, I thought that maybe I could include another feature, Sample time, and duplicate my training data for different intervals in order to train on this.
For example, for a single training instance:
Training data would become:
   Sample time (minutes before), Sample number of items bought, Total number bought (y)

1             100                          50                          250
2             50                           52                          250
3             10                           75                          250
4             5                            150                         250
5             2                            190                         250

                     

Test data
   Sample time (minutes before), Sample number of items bought, Total number bought (y)

1             53                           25                          ?
                    

Here the Sample number of items bought feature is meaningless without the sample time, so I'm not sure this approach makes sense. Is there a better way to handle this, while still using a Random Forest model?
